# what is the best way to handle new clients using select() in a server?

Tags: c, sockets, select, asynchronous

I want to write a asynchronous socket server in C, but before I do I'm doing some research. Looking at the select() socket example shown here: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Server-Example.html#Server-Example I can see that the example program will only accept one client per select loop (if I'm reading it right). So if there are 20 clients and two more try to connect, will it only accept the 21st client then process the other 20 (worst case, assuming all 20 others require reading) and THEN accept the 22nd? Would it be better if I break the loop after accepting a client so it can select() again and take care of all pending clients before processing connected ones? Or does that defeat the purpose of using select()? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server pattern shown in the example you linked to is fine; there isn't any significant problem introduced by the loop only accepting one socket per iteration.

The key point to keep in mind is that in a well-designed select() loop, the *only* place the process should *ever* block is inside the select() call.  In particular, if coded correctly, the server will never block inside send(), recv(), or accept().  It's best to set all sockets to non-blocking mode (via fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)) in order to guarantee this behavior.

Given that, the precise ordering of "which clients get serviced first within any particular event loop iteration" doesn't matter, because all clients' sockets get handled very soon after they have data ready-for-read (or buffer space ready-for-write), and all new connections get accepted quickly.

Comment: Of course, you could limit the amount of data you send/receive in each iteration, to avoid long requests stalling shorter ones. I think the Zeus web server did something along those lines. You should probably also add some randomness as to what requests you process first.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I could cheat a bug in my program by breaking after accepting a client, but that would actually decrease performance. I guess I can't take the easy way out.

Answer (score 1):

select() leaves it up to the programmer to decide how to handle notifications. One call to select() can indicate that any or all sockets have bytes to be read and some connection requests to process. The application can process all the notifications before calling select() or process one notification before calling select() again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use poll() on the listening socket after accept() to see if there are more clients waiting to connect.

Note the the number of concurrent connect-attempts is handled by the backlog parameter to listen(server_sock, backlog) - backlog is 1 in the sample you reference.